# How do I use Splinter/chromium-chromedriver in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux, splinter

This is my dockerfile code and my .py code uses splinter for the chromedriver.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY requirements.txt . 

RUN apk update && \
    apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev && \
    apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add chromium chromium-chromedriver && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.[acpw]* ipaexg00301*


COPY . /app
```

Then when I run my program I get this error message.
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127"

I've tried everything to get this to work to no avail. Help would be appreciated.